# plans and subset of rows in pyfftw

Tags: pyfftw

I want to use `pyfft` to repeatedly compute the discrete Fourier transform of a subset of rows for a two-dimensional array. I do not know in advance which rows I need to transform, that depends on the output from the previous round. I do know that doing it for all rows is wasteful.

It is my understanding that a 'plan' in `FFTW3` is associated with the type of transform (c2c, r2c, etc) and the input/output length, which is always a vector in the 1D case. In `pyfftw` it looks like a 'plan' is associated to the type of transform and the input/output shape, so my interpretation is that it uses the same `FFTW3` plan for every row.

My question is: is it possible to use the same `FFTW3` plan for *some* of the rows, without creating separate `pyfftw.FFTW` objects for all possible combinations of rows?

On a different note, I am wondering how `pyfftw` uses multiple cores: does it use multiple cores for each row (this appears natural in view of `FFTW3` documentation) or does it farm out different rows to different cores (which was my initial assumption)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a numpy array from a view, you can plan for it with pyFFTW - all valid numpy arrays *should* work just fine.

This means several things:

1. Your array needs to have regular strides, but those strides can be arbitrary.
2. ND arrays are planned as ND transforms, with the selected axes being used.
3. You can probably do something cunning with stride tricks and it will probably work (but might not do what you expect if you do something too nefarious like overlapping rows and then use threads).

One solution that I've used quite a bit is to copy the rows that you want to transform into an interim array, and transforming that. You might well find that's the fastest option (particularly when you can allow for getting the byte offset correct).

Obviously, this doesn't work if you always have a different number of rows. You might still find that if you plan for the largest number of rows that are transformed and then copy in a subset you still do faster than otherwise.

The problem you're going to come up against, even if you go down to the C level, is that the planning overhead might well dominate if you're changing your transform sizes often.

You could also try `pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft` which is normally faster that numpy and has the ability to cache repeated transform sizes.

Comment: Henry, thanks for pyfftw and your speedy reply! Could you clarify the second bullet item? If you only select axis "-1" for a 2D array, does the planning happen only for a single row (e.g., the first)? 

I have tried pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft and it works great but I am trying to squeeze a bit more juice out of my machine.

Also, if you could say something about my second question I would appreciate it.

Comment: No, the axes argument tells pyFFTW which axes to use, not which specific slice to use. If you want to slice an array, you need to do this first.

Comment: After studying your pyfftw code as well as the FFTW manual in detail, I realized my question was more about FFTW than about pyfftw. The details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503726).