# repeatedly computing the fft over a varying number of rows

Tags: fftw

I am interested in computing the fft of the first rows of a matrix, but I do not know in advance how many rows I need. I need to do this repeatedly but the number of rows I need to transform can change.

I will illustrate with the following example. Suppose I have a 100 by 128 array. If I plan for 1-dimensional fft's on each row, FFTW produces the following plan:

```
(dft-ct-dit/8
  (dftw-direct-8/28-x100 "t2fv_8_sse2")
  (dft-vrank>=1-x8/1
    (dft-direct-16-x100 "n1fv_16_sse2")))
```

Although I don't fully understand this output, I do see the key ingredients: 1) This is a single Cooley-Tucker pass, note that 8*16=128. 2) Because of the x100 postfix on two lines, the plan states that this needs to happen for 100 rows.

I see three possibilities:

- One-size-fits-all planning: plan for the 100 by 128 array, and execute this big plan even when only the first (say) 20 rows are needed. 
  Pros: we need only one plan so there is little planning overhead. Cons: potentially substantial performance loss in the execution phase (transforming more than I need).
- Exhaustive planning: obtain plans using the same input/output array but for a all possible number of rows. In the example I would have 100 plans, where plan i carries out the fft for each of the first i rows. Pros: Transforming exactly what I need. Cons: Experiments show that I have to pay the planning penalty over and over, even though say for i=50 the plan will be the same as above but with x50 instead of x100. (I suppose there is no guarantee this will indeed be the plan identified by the FFTW planner, but I wouldn't mind losing "optimality" if I can cut out the planning time.)
- Single-row planning: plan for a single row and use a loop to move data into input, transform, and move data out of output. Pros: I'm transforming exactly what I need. Cons: it seems to me this removes a lot of the FFTW optimizations, for instance when I use multiple threads. (I'm generally confused how multithreading works in FFTW since it is ill-documented... I know threading information is part of the plan, but printing the plan doesn't display any of it. This is off-topic though.)

I was thinking that I would combine all three ideas by first creating the one-size-fits-all plan, modifying this plan 99 times in a for loop instead of planning for the different sizes, and executing as under the exhaustive-planning approach. However I can't find any documentation on the plan/wisdom format, the output of wisdom with hexadecimal numbers is impenetrable. So I am wondering how I can carry out this hybrid approach.

Comment: You can tune the level of optimisation by using flags `FFTW_ESTIMATE` instead of `FFTW_MEASURE` or `FFTW_PATIENT`. That way, the input array is not overwritten and plans are quickly built. See http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html Could you please tell us if a different plan is chosen?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? You shouldn't be needing to know what the planner is doing. The whole point of planning is to give you the fastest transform for a given size. If you change the size, of course it needs to plan again. If you want to compromise on that, you can either use `FFTW_ESTIMATE` which is a faster plan, or you can change the way in which you're using FFTW (which is the better solution IMO because it can completely cut out the planning). You might find that the tricks don't add anything to the actual processing, but they are dependent on your actual problem.

Comment: See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @francis: I realize I can use `FFTW_ESTIMATE` to speed up the planning and in this small example it may indeed give the same plan... but in general the example may not be small and the planning effort could be substantial even for `FFTW_ESTIMATE` especially since I may have many rows.

Comment: @henry: thanks for your x-y reference, I have reworked the question. I am intrigued by your comment that I can use FFTW and cut out the planning, in some sense I'm looking for that.

Comment: @Ton you will likely find that planning for one row and then just looping over the rows is going to be about as fast as any pre-planned solution (since you're only doing 1D transforms). Of course, for this to be true you should ideally writing in C with all the optimisations on. Also, make sure your array has a suitable length such that the alignment is consistent - go for 32 bytes to work with AVX. This may mean you'll need some packing to get it to work properly - though typically good lengths are also fast lengths.

Comment: @henry: I tried this for various sizes and I found that there is a 2-20% penalty for using this approach with the sizes I have tried.
It appears therefore that there is a performance benefit to the `howmany` and `howmany_dims` functionality even when you have the best possible alignment, it's not just a convenient interface.

Comment: @Ton did you align properly?